# C# iText7 OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions, itext7

I am using iText7 to generate a PDF file of name badges inside of an Azure Function. There are 471 people, and it prints 6 badges per page in the document. When I run the function locally, it works, but memory usage jumps to almost 3GB. When I deploy the function to Azure, it eventually throws an OutOfMemoryException.

Is there a way to make this code use less memory? Each image is about 90k so it should only be about 40mb of images...which is about how big the resulting PDF file is.

```
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req, ILogger log) {
    try {
        long conferenceId = long.Parse(req.Query["conferenceId"]);
        string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();

        var people = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Person>>(requestBody);

        using var outputStream = new MemoryStream();
        using var finalDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(outputStream).SetSmartMode(false));
        finalDoc.SetDefaultPageSize(iText.Kernel.Geom.PageSize.LETTER);
        using Document document = new Document(finalDoc, iText.Kernel.Geom.PageSize.LETTER, true);
        document.SetMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

        var size = ResizeKeepAspect(new SixLabors.ImageSharp.Size(1200, 900), 287.5f, 300);

        foreach (var person in people) {
            var i = people.IndexOf(person);
            log.LogInformation($"Generating badge {i} of {people.Count} for {person.FirstName} {person.LastName}");
            var pageNum = ((int)i / 6) + 1; // 6 per page;
            var colNum = i % 2 == 0 ? 0 : 1;
            var rowNum = 2 - (i % 6 / 2);

            using var client = new HttpClient();
            var bytes = await client.GetByteArrayAsync($"https://redacted.com/fetchBadgeImage?conferenceId={conferenceId}&userId={person.Id}");
            ImageData qrImageData = ImageDataFactory.Create(bytes);

            Image qrImage = new Image(qrImageData)
            .ScaleAbsolute(size.Width, size.Height).SetFixedPosition(pageNum, 18 + (colNum * 288), 72f + (size.Height * rowNum) + (.5f * rowNum), 1200);
            document.Add(qrImage);
        }
        document.Close();

        return new FileContentResult(outputStream.ToArray(), "application/pdf");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.LogError("ERROR OCCURED: " + e.Message);
        log.LogError(e.Message);
        log.LogError(e.ToString());
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: One thing to consider is how your instantiating the `HttpClient`. The docs say to create a single instance and reuse it, don't create a new instance for every call. [HttpClient Instancing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.7.1#instancing)

Comment: @quaabaam Thanks. I've tried both ways and `HTTPClient` doesn't seem to make any difference

Comment: Use a profiler, should be easy to spot where the memory is being used.

Comment: If you are looking for a performance improvement advise, do you mind actually making sure your code is runnable for everyone? Right now it heavily depends on your infrastructure so you will likely either get random low quality advise, or no advise at all

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to run a memory profiler to see where all that memory is being taken up to really know what's going on.

Visual Studio has the ability to do memory / GC tracing and provide a report, but experience trying to use it shows it to be *very* slow in analysing large reports and not the easiest to gain actionable insights from if you do manage to get a report out.

Instead, I'd recommend you take a look at [dotMemory](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/) from JetBrains. I've used this several times myself when investigating memory usage of stuff I'm working on and found it to be far quicker and easier to use than Visual Studio's offering. Whilst it's not free, there is a 30 day free trial you can use here.

To try and help with the original question, one thing to bear in mind is the OOM error might be caused by GC heap fragmentation rather than exhausting physical memory.

You are allocating a `byte[]` inside a loop when fetching the images and you mentioned that each image is about 90k in size - this might be causing you issues with the LOH since any object bigger than [85k](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/large-object-heap) will be allocated there. This heap is also not collected very often so has certainly caused people issues in the past because of this.

To prevent this fragmentation, you can set the [LargeObjectHeapCompactionMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.gcsettings.largeobjectheapcompactionmode?view=net-6.0) option along with a `GC.Collect()` call after each loop iteration to clean up all these temporary image buffers.